# Set image source and background image with javascript

Tags: javascript, image, dom, background-image

I've looked at many other posts and I think I'm using the exact syntax suggested.  However, I'm not getting the images to show up.  I have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abalter/An7r5/).  Is it a jsfiddle issue?  It's also not working on a website I'm working on.

```
<div id="divtest">Hello</div>
<img id="imgtest" />
<img id="imgreal" src="http://www.premiumbeat.com/blog/wpcontent/uploads/2012/12/free.jpeg" />

var string = "url('http://www.premiumbeat.com/blog/wpcontent/uploads/2012/12/free.jpeg')";
alert(string)
document.getElementByID("divtest").style.backgroundImage = string;
document.getElementByID("imgtest").src = string;
```

Comment: Maybe because the image doesn't exist? Otherwise it is fine. Looks like a jsfiddle issue.

Comment: JS is case-sensitive: `document.getElementByID` !== `document.getElementById`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two minor problems:

1. `getElementByID` is not a function; `getElementById` is.
2. The format for a url is different for an image source and a background image. Try this:

   `var string = 'http://www.premiumbeat.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/free.jpeg';
   document.getElementById("divtest").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + string + "')";
   document.getElementById("imgtest").src = string;`

Answer (score 3):

Replace `getElementByID` by `getElementById` and there is another error in your code:

you write:

```
var string = "url('http://www.premiumbeat.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/free.jpeg')";

document.getElementById("imgtest").src = string;
```

But `src` doesn't need `url(`, so you should write :

```
var str1 = "url('http://www.premiumbeat.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/free.jpeg')";
document.getElementById("divtest").style.backgroundImage = str1 ;

var str2 = 'http://www.premiumbeat.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/free.jpeg';
document.getElementById("imgtest").src = str2;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Your's was just as good, but Bubbles is first as I scroll down.  Thanks!