# set background-image to html using js

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
bg = "http//example.com/img.png";
html = '<div style="background-image:url('+bg+')>'
```

What's wrong with my concatenation above? I did see the img path but the background image doesn't appear.

Comment: Can you fiddle your code here http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: `<div style="background-image:url(\"'+bg+'\"")>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055541/set-image-source-and-background-image-with-javascript

Comment: @BrijeshBhatt — Quotes are optional inside CSS `url()`s.

Comment: but you can't open a quote without closing it

Comment: '<div style="background-image:url("'+bg+'")">'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

close your quotes

```
html = '<div style="background-image:url('+bg+')">'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Code should be like

```
bg = "http//example.com/img.png";
html = '<div style="background-image:url('+bg+')">'
```

Quotes missing at last

Answer (score -4):

Ops. sorry.!!
Just close your qoutes.

```
'<div style="background-image:url('+bg+')">'
```